# Is JobID Unique across Business Units

Tags: marketing-cloud

If i have three business units BU1 being the parent, BU2 and BU3 being the children. I then send emails in all three BUs. Could i expect the same JobID generated for an email i send in BU1 or BU2 with BU3 (or any other combination)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JobID is unique on all Business Units. All sends are logged on the same DataViews: _Sent, _Click,.. no matter from which Business Unit you are sending your emails.

> Job data view provides results for **all email send jobs in the
>   Enterprise**. Results are not categorized by send method.

Reference

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_job.htm&type=5